# Community detection for larger than memory embeddings dataset

Tags: python, algorithm, word-embedding

I currently have a dataset of textual embeddings (768 dimensions). The current number of records is ~1 million. I am looking to detect related embeddings through a community detection algorithm. For small data sets, I have been able to use this one:

https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/applications/clustering/fast_clustering.py

It works great, but, it doesn't really scale as the data set grows larger than memory.

The key here is that I am able to specify a threshold for community matches. I have been able to find clustering algorithms that scale to larger than memory, but I always have to specify a fixed number of clusters ahead of time. I need the system to detect the number of clusters for me.

I'm certain there are a class of algorithms - and hopefully a python library - that can handle this situation, but I have been unable to locate it. Does anyone know of an algorithm or a solution I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems small enough that you could just rent a bigger computer.

Nevertheless, to answer the question, typically the play is to cluster the data into a few chunks (overlapping or not) that fit in memory and then apply a higher-quality in-memory clustering algorithm to each chunk. One typical strategy for cosine similarity is to cluster by [SimHashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimHash), but

1. there's a whole literature out there;
2. if you already have a scalable clustering algorithm you like, you can use that.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will investigate the bigger computer. To clarify one thing, this will probably scale up to 10 million, but not more. Regarding the literature, any pointers would be most welcome. I am not always sure what to search for...

Comment: Should've also said, thank for the pointer on SimHash. That may be in fact what I'm looking for. Cheers.

Comment: I spent some time digging into SimHashes/etc today. The thing I am unclear about is how they work with non-binary vectors. All my embeddings are using floats. I have made some progress with the splitting into chunks and my existing algorithm though, so perhaps that is the best approach.

Comment: @DanDiephouse you choose a random vector with independent Gaussian elements and take the sign of its dot product with each of your vectors.

Comment: Any pointers to that in literature/web? I'm struggling to translate that into exact practice.

Comment: @DanDiephouse Section 3 of https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr04/cos598B/bib/CharikarEstim.pdf